# NPM update error

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Tried to upgrade my npm but go these errors. :S
Anyone have can point me to the right guide that would be awesome.

I am running windows 10

```
C:\Users\kavas>npm -v
2.14.12

C:\Users\kavas>npm cache clean

C:\Users\kavas>npm update -g --unsafe-perm node-red

> bcrypt@0.8.5 install C:\Users\kavas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

/
C:\Users\kavas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framew
ork 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it i
s installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\kavas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\bcrypt\build\binding.sln
]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kavas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN deprecated i18next-client@1.10.3: you can use npm install i18next from version 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update npm by using this command:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Note that this command will remove your current version of npm. Make sure to use `sudo npm install -g npm` if on a Mac.

You can also update all outdated local packages by doing `npm update` without any arguments, or global packages by doing `npm update -g`

If you want to update NODE-RED, try this command:

```
npm update -g node-red
```